# Expanding Solr search: "volcano" to match "volcanic"

Tags: solr, sunspot-solr, websolr

I have websolr setup on my rails app running on heroku. I just noticed that the search for "volcano" did not return all the results I would have expected. Specifically, it did return a result which included both "volcanic" and "stratovolcanoes".

How do I need to modify the solr configuration to address this?

This is the relevant section from my schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**Addition**: I don't think this is relevant, but just in case:

My Rails Photo.rb model is setup like this:

```
  searchable do
    text :caption, :stored => true
    text :category do
      category.breadcrumb
    end

    integer :user_id
    integer :category_id
    string :caption
    string :rights
  end
```

Caption and category are the two text fields I'm searching on. Caption is free-form text, whereas Category is a text string like "Earth Science > Volcanoes"

This is my synonyms config that shows in websolr (I added the last line):

```
#some test synonym mappings unlikely to appear in real input text
aaa => aaaa
bbb => bbbb1 bbbb2
ccc => cccc1,cccc2
a\=>a => b\=>b
a\,a => b\,b
fooaaa,baraaa,bazaaa

# Some synonym groups specific to this example
GB,gib,gigabyte,gigabytes
MB,mib,megabyte,megabytes
Television, Televisions, TV, TVs
#notice we use "gib" instead of "GiB" so any WordDelimiterFilter coming
#after us won't split it into two words.

# Synonym mappings can be used for spelling correction too
pixima => pixma

volcano => volcanic,stratovolcanoes
```

Comment: what are the indexed terms ??? and what are you searching for ?

Comment: @Jayendra, I added more details to my initial question. The user is searching for "volcano" and it's showing some results, but it's missing results that include the word "volcanic" and "stratovolcanoes".

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is caused by the introduction of `SnowballPorterFilterFactory`

Including this in your analyzer lists causes Solr to apply [Stemming](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Stemming) to your terms. Particularly, in this case Solr does [Porter Stemming](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/def.txt)

If you do not need stemming, you could remove that analyzer.

Comment: To add to this answer: stemmers are imperfect. For Porter stemmer `organization and organism, volcano and volcanic` stems to : `organ and organ , volcano and volcan`. Nothing to worry about, unless your search users are particularly interested in volcanoes!

Comment: another addition, none of those stemmers will work for "stratovolcanoes" if you really need that result and you only have a few of these technical terms you can add these lists of words to synonyms like stratovolcanoes => volcano

Comment: @Srikanth, I don't think that's right. I just recently added the SnowballPorterFilterFactory but I've been having this issue for awhile. The Snowball filter fixed a separate issue I was having (the search for "planet" was not matching the text "planets").

Comment: @kali and atichnyu: I did find the ability to add synonyms but I was hoping to find a more general solution. It sounds like both of you are saying there isn't one, which I was afraid of. My site is a search engine for science teachers so volcano -> volcanic is not an edge case for me. :)

Comment: @keith one of the factories may work for you. Just try all 3 for english. The original solr.PorterStemFilterFactory is very aggressive to my taste but it will produce most number of matches in many cases. solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory is more intelligent and will produce less number of results with more accuracy, and it is almost 3 times slower.

Comment: @kali Interesting. When you say "try all 3 for english", what are those three? I'd like to give that a go but I'm not sure where to find the list. (I'm very new to solr)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not get desired results for specific cases with stemming, you could add a solr.SynonymFilterFactory filter like descibed [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#SynonymFilter):

```
<fieldtype name="syn" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="syn.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

You will then be able to maintain a synonym file:

```
volcano => volcanic, stratovolcanoes
```

Comment: Although cumbersome, I think this may be the only solution. I'm trying it out but it's not working. I'm using websolr so the web interface has a synonyms tab which shows a config file. (I edited my question to show more details) I added the line you specified (but I removed the space after the ","). Immediately after saving the config the index stopped showing results, so I assumed I needed to reindex before the synonym would go into effect. But after reindexing I'm still the stratovolcanoes results when I search "volcano". Any ideas?